# php loop doesnt work with $i assigned to a 21 digit number

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a php loop like :

```
for($i = $_GET['start']; $i < $_GET['end']; $i++){

echo $i;

}
```

when $i is assigned to something like `100000000000000000000` the script doesnt run and it returns no errors!! is there anywway I can fix this?

thanks

Comment: what are start/end for? do you really need this many numbers? this loop will take ages

Comment: I bet it runs, it's just that the for body is not executed because of an integer overflow.

Comment: no it wont, the start would be like : `100000000000000000000` and the end would be like `100000000000000001000` and dont ask me why I chose to do this :), I need it this way

Comment: no, it loads and stops but nothing shows!!!!!

Comment: I got this working for you and edited my answer below. Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you are using is too large for PHP to handle.

"The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value."

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Here is the solution that I tested using strings instead of integers and it works:

```
$start = (string)$_GET['start'];
$end = (string)$_GET['end'];

for($i = $start; strcmp($i, $end); $i = bcadd($i, 1)){
    echo $i . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: ok does that mean that php wont be able to do math on the value like `$int = 100000000000000000000` and `$int++` ?

Comment: You might be able to do a for loop implementation using the BC Math functions. http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: although yes, too large for an int, from the manual: `If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return a float instead. ` You should be able to do a loop on floats.

Comment: True. However, a starting value and ending value that have 21 digits converted to a float may lose enough precision so as to evaluate to the same number and not run the loop and therefore the script runs and does not return any errors as ahoura is describing.

Comment: I still think a good solution may be to convert start and end into strings and utilize BC Math functions in the for loop expressions.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a solution that I tested and made sure it works. Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to specify which range of numbers your script should support.

Then you need to find the right data structures to handle the data, e.g. `integer` - or more likely in your case - [`gmp` numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).

Then you can just code. The `for` loop works as announced, you might want to not hard-code it against `$_GET` probably.

Comment: so what you are suggesting is to use something like `$start = gmp_init($_GET['start']);
$end = gmp_init($_GET['end']);

for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++){`  ?

Comment: The comparison and the increment operation need to be done with gmp functions as well: [`gmp_add`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-add.php); [`gmp_cmp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-cmp.php).

Answer (score 0):

First, do not put `$_GET['start']` and `$_GET['end']` directly in your code.

Instead, assign these to variables and check to make sure they are numeric and in range.

For example: end cannot be less than start, etc...

```
for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++){

echo $i;

}
```

Second, a number that large will hang your server.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the difference between start and end so your loop vars are smaller:

```
<?php

$min = 0;
$max = $_GET['end'] - $_GET['start'];
for($i = $min; $i < $max; $i++){
    echo $i + $_GET['start'];
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer to your question.  since you refuse to tell us what you actually need it for.  it produces the correct response to your example.

Comment: this does work, try putting `100000000000000000000` as start and `100000000000000001000` as end in the code above, it will not work

Comment: @ahoura - The real solution to your problem is getting those int values within a reasonable range. With the start/end set to the values you suggest, using `var_export` on the `$_GET` variable results in this: `array ( 'end' => 1.0E+20, 'start' => 1.0E+20, )`. As you can see they are the same, so in my example `$max` results in `0`. Thus the loop never runs.